# Conditionally choosing the column to filter on in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My data have this basic shape:

```
ID <- c(1:9)
Treatment <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C", 3))
v1 <- c(38, 44, 43, rep(NA, 3), 29, 49, 71)
v2 <- c(rep(NA, 3), 59, 32, 50, 73, 69, 34)

df <- tibble(ID, Treatment, v1, v2)
df

     ID Treatment    v1    v2
  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 A            38    NA
2     2 A            44    NA
3     3 A            43    NA
4     4 B            NA    59
5     5 B            NA    32
6     6 B            NA    50
7     7 C            29    73
8     8 C            49    69
9     9 C            71    34
```

I want to filter it such that the maximum row for v2 within each treatment is kept. However, if v2 is NA, then I want to pick the maximum of v1 for each treatment. My desired output would look like:

```
desired_ID desired_Treatment desired_v1 desired_v2
     <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>
1        2 A                         44         NA
2        4 B                         NA         59
3        7 C                         29         73
```

I'm trying to use `filter` in `dplyr` for this, but this code...

```
attempt <- df %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  filter(v1 == max(v1, na.rm = TRUE) | v2 == max(v2, na.rm = TRUE))
```

...causes two rows from Treatment C to be kept (the max for v1 in row 9 and the max for v2 in row 7), which is not what I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if/else` construct within `filter`, for example:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  filter(if (all(is.na(v2))) v1 == max(v1) else v2 == max(v2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Treatment [3]
     ID Treatment    v1    v2
  <int> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     2 A            44    NA
2     4 B            NA    59
3     7 C            29    73
```

Alternatively, also `slice` with `which.max` can be used:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  slice(if (all(is.na(v2))) which.max(v1) else which.max(v2))
```